# Failure to load or find main class

Tags: java, ant

I'm attempting to use ant to build my jar with all its dependencies but keep getting the `Error: Could not find or load main class main.SteamduckBot` when I attempt to run the jar with the `java -jar ircbot.jar`  command.

This is my build.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="ircbot" default="jar">

    <!-- Name of the output .jar file -->
    <property name="jar.name" value="ircbot.jar" />

    <!-- Base directory for distribution target -->
    <property name="deploy.home" value="." />

    <!-- Base directory for compilation targets -->
    <property name="build.home" value="." />

    <!-- Main class -->
    <property name="main.class" value="main.SteamduckBot" />

    <!-- The base directory for all libraries (jar) files -->
    <property name="lib.home" value="lib" />

    <target name="jar" description="Create jar and MANIFEST.MF">

        <pathconvert property="libs.project" pathsep=" ">
            <mapper>
                <chainedmapper>
                    <!-- remove absolute path -->
                    <flattenmapper />

                    <!-- add lib/ prefix -->
                    <globmapper from="*" to="lib/*" />
                </chainedmapper>
            </mapper>
            <path>
                <!-- lib.home contains all jar files,
                                                in several subdirectories -->
                <fileset dir="${lib.home}">
                    <include name="**/*.jar" />
                </fileset>
            </path>

        </pathconvert>

        <!-- create the jar -->
        <jar jarfile="${deploy.home}/${jar.name}" basedir="${build.home}">

            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Built-By" value="${user.name}" />
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}" />

                <!-- Finally, use the generated libs path -->
                <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${libs.project}" />
            </manifest>

        </jar>
    </target>

</project>
```

Ant builds just fine but obviously I must be doing something wrong - Where is my error?

This is the structure of my project: 
[image]

And here is the contents of the resulting jar : This is the contents of the jar : http://pastebin.com/iYQGsutE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see in your build file where you compile your Java files to .class files and where you include these .class files inside the jar. It seems like you're storing the sources files inside the jar, and not the class files.

Check the contents of the jar.

Comment: So you confirmed what I thought. You created a jar with source files and not with compiled class files. Your build file must first compile the source files, and then create a jar containing the compiled class files. No .java file should be in the jar.

Comment: Read the documentation for the javac ant task. It explains everything.